# Format Column Date for Admin Grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I was wondering how can I format a column into a certain date format? Right now I'm getting this format

[image]

But what I wanted was something like `MM/d/Y` format. I already tried this

```
<column name="created_at">      
  <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
        <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Date</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd/MM/Y</item>
     </item>
   </argument>
</column>
```

But it didn't work. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify date format by defining in the xml file directly as below.

```xml
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
    <settings>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Order Date</label>
        <dateFormat>MMMM d, Y</dateFormat><!--  this is the dateformat you can specify -->
    </settings>
</column>
```

in case if you dynamically show the date format that you can use below also

```xml
<column name="created_at" class="Vendor\YourModule\Component\Columns\OrderGrid"> <!-- add your custom class for dateformat -->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Date</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

refer `OrderGrid.php`

```php
<?php

namespace Vendor\YourModule\Component\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class OrderGrid extends Column
{
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $contextInterface,
        UiComponentFactory $componentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($contextInterface, $componentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        $dateFormat = "dd/MM/Y";

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $date = '';
                if ($item[$this->getData('name')] != '' && $item[$this->getData('name')] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00') {
                    $date = date($dateFormat, strtotime($item[$this->getData('name')]));
                }
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $date;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to achieve the same in Grid.php block ?